# How do i draw the trail of a button movement?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to make an application which controls, through a `trackbar`, the movement of 3 different buttons.

The buttons move towards a center point as well as in a circular way. What I intend to do is to draw the trail of the buttons movements: every time a button changes its location color that pixel it "lands" on.

I am coding in C#, a WFA project.

This is the code for the movement of buttons:

```
private void trackBar1_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //161, 114
        double sinX, cosX, sinY, cosY, sinZ, cosZ;
        sinX = Math.Sin(trackBar1.Value / 57.29);
        cosX = Math.Cos(trackBar1.Value / 57.29);
        sinX = Math.Truncate((360 - trackBar1.Value)/4 * sinX);
        cosX = Math.Truncate((360 - trackBar1.Value) / 4 * cosX);
        button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(161 + (int)sinX, 114 + (int)cosX);

        sinY = Math.Sin((trackBar1.Value + 120) / 57.29);
        cosY = Math.Cos((trackBar1.Value + 120)/ 57.29);
        sinY = Math.Truncate((360 - trackBar1.Value) / 4 * sinY);
        cosY = Math.Truncate((360 - trackBar1.Value) / 4 * cosY);
        button2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(161 + (int)sinY, 114 + (int)cosY);

        sinZ = Math.Sin((trackBar1.Value + 240) / 57.29);
        cosZ = Math.Cos((trackBar1.Value + 240) / 57.29);
        sinZ = Math.Truncate((360 - trackBar1.Value) / 4 * sinZ);
        cosZ = Math.Truncate((360 - trackBar1.Value) / 4 * cosZ);
        button3.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(161 + (int)sinZ, 114 + (int)cosZ);

    }
```

[Moves like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/arofj.png) [towards a center point.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m6fZA.png)

Comment: I am sure people would, however you have just explained your application, its very unclear what you are trying to do, what its doing, or how you are doing it. Id sagest pasting code or images of your intended behavior or something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generate a filed in your form that can hold all the points
List track = new List();

Save the first location of button in the list in the constructor:

```
public MyForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    // Make sure you put this code after the InitializeComponent:
    this.track.Add(button3.Location)
}
```

then store the positions of your button in that list on move event:

```
private void trackBar1_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //rest of your code
    button3.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(161 + (int)sinZ, 114 + (int)cosZ);
    this.track.Add(button3.Location)
}
```

and then handle the Form.Paint method as below:

```
private void MyForm_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Red);
    foreach(Point point in track)
    {
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(point, new Size(1,1));
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, rect);
    }
}
```

Comment: It does what i want it to do, but gets pretty slow after a while.(moving the trackbar with arrow keys and drawing) Any ideas why?

Comment: I think i understand why, every time i scroll it just adds more items to the list and that means every time i scroll it has to paint the previous pixels as well, so around 360 * 3 pixels.

Comment: I haven't done this before but from the top of my mind you may use this: `Parallel.ForEach(track, x => {
                Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(p, new Size(1, 1));
                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, rect);
            });`